# Excel formula to generate conditional random value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get a formula that will generate a random value based on a defined condition.  Since I may not be explaining this correctly here is my example:

I have a Column A that contains ID numbers.  I have a Column B that contains various statuses (Approved, Denied, etc.)  In a given cell on another worksheet, I would like to generate a random application number from Column A that has a corresponding status "Approved" in Column B.  I have tried various techniques of using INDEX and RANDBETWEEN combinations but can't get to what I need.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible expression:

```
=INDEX(A1:A30,INDEX(LARGE((B1:B30="Approved")*ROW(A1:A30),ROW(A1:A30)),1+INT(RAND()*COUNTIF(B1:B30,"Approved"))))
```

[image]

It assumes that the ID is in `A1:A30`, 
and the status is in `B1:B30`.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will filter the "Approved" and then randomly choose one to return:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",B:B)))/($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",B:B))="Approved"),RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(B:B,"Approved"))))
```

[image]

---

Note:

It is Volatile and every time Excel re calculates it will also recalculate.  You can see this by hitting F9, which forces Excel to re calculate.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  Seems to work, going to apply it to my application and see how the end result is.